# Issues in creating pysimplegui or Tkinter graph GUI by reading csv file , cleaning it and plotting graph (histogram+PDF)

Tags: csv, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter, data-cleaning

I want to create GUI which should automatically clean data in csv file once selected and plot superimposed PDF & histogram graph. I have uploaded basic python program which generates the required graph but I am unbale to convert it into interface.  I guess, only "open file" & "plot" buttons would suffice the requirement.  [image- want to retrieve data from 'N'th column (13) only with skipping top 4 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCgsA.jpg)

I am basically from metallurgy background and trying my hands in this field.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

raw_data = pd.read_csv("D:/Project/Python/NDC/Outlier_ND/800016_DAT.csv",skiprows=4,header=None)
clean = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
data1 = clean.iloc[:, [13]]

Q1 = data1.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = data1.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1

data_IQR = data1[~((data1 < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(data1 > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
data_IQR.shape
print(data1.shape)
print(data_IQR.shape)

headerList = ['Actual_MR']
data_IQR.to_csv(r'D:\Project\Python\NDC\Outlier_ND\800016_DAT_IQR.csv', header=headerList, index=False)
data = pd.read_csv("D:/Project/Python/NDC/Outlier_ND/800016_DAT_IQR.csv")

mean, sd = norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=25, density=True, alpha=0.6, facecolor = '#2ab0ff', edgecolor='#169acf', linewidth=0.5)
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mean, sd)
plt.plot(x, p, 'red', linewidth=2)
title = " Graph \n mean: {:.2f} and SD: {:.2f}".format(mean, sd)
plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel('MR')
plt.ylabel('Pr')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code demo how PySimpleGUI to work with matplotlib, detail please find all remark in script.

```py
import math, random
from pathlib import Path

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# 1. Define the class as the interface between matplotlib and PySimpleGUI
class Canvas(FigureCanvasTkAgg):
    """
    Create a canvas for matplotlib pyplot under tkinter/PySimpleGUI canvas
    """
    def __init__(self, figure=None, master=None):
        super().__init__(figure=figure, master=master)
        self.canvas = self.get_tk_widget()
        self.canvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

# 2. create PySimpleGUI window, a fixed-size Frame with Canvas which expand in both x and y.
font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)
layout = [
    [sg.Input(expand_x=True, key='Path'),
     sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("ALL CSV Files", "*.csv"), ("ALL Files", "*.*"))),
     sg.Button('Plot')],
    [sg.Frame("", [[sg.Canvas(background_color='green', expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='Canvas')]], size=(640, 480))],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Exit')]
]
window = sg.Window('Matplotlib', layout, finalize=True)

# 3. Create a matplotlib canvas under sg.Canvas or sg.Graph
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
canvas = Canvas(fig, window['Canvas'].Widget)

# 4. initial for figure
ax.set_title(f"Sensor Data")
ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y axis")
ax.set_xlim(0, 1079)
ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
ax.grid()
canvas.draw()                       # do Update to GUI canvas

# 5. PySimpleGUI event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Plot':
        """
        path = values['Path']
        if not Path(path).is_file():
            continue
        """
        # 6. Get data from path and plot from here
        ax.cla()                    # Clear axes first if required
        ax.set_title(f"Sensor Data")
        ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
        ax.set_ylabel("Y axis")
        ax.grid()
        theta = random.randint(0, 359)
        x = [degree for degree in range(1080)]
        y = [math.sin((degree+theta)/180*math.pi) for degree in range(1080)]
        ax.plot(x, y)
        canvas.draw()               # do Update to GUI canvas

# 7. Close window to exit
window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, really appreciate your help. But still stuck at assigning buttons for loading and cleaning csv file.

Comment: Hi, solved the issue and created a standalone exe also. you may pl close this issue

Comment: There's something wrong about scale if we use `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` for figure, so update it by using `matplotlib.figure.Figure` for matplotlib 3.5.1